# Display the current time on the prompt by configuring PS1

Tags: bash

I am trying to configure `PS1` to display the current time, here is my current variable

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ env | grep -i 'ps1'
PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

The result planed is

```
me@host; 09:00 AM: ~/Downloads$
```

> \T is expanded into the current time in 12-hour format,

Configure it temporally

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h;\T: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$"
```

Unfortunately, the prompt does not change.

What' s the problem with my usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you double-quote, then variable expansion will strip out the `debian_chroot` sections
2. Two settings are embedded in the string but you only set one:

   - the first (which you changed) sets the title of the terminal window
   - the second (which you didn't change) sets the command prompt

Try something like:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h;\T: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\];\T:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```